# Whats the difference between V8 and ES8

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-2017

I am wondering what is the difference between V8 and the ES8?

Comment: Did you try google first?

Comment: V8 is a JavaScript engine, ES8 is a language specification

Answer (score 1):

The same as between raven and writing desk.

V8 is an engine — it's software that executes your Javascript code.

ES8, which is short for ECMAScript version 8, is the standard of Javascript language. V8 may support different versions of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 0):

ES8 (or better name it ES2017) is the programming language standard.

And V8 is the implementation of that standard from Google.

Comment: Why is it better to name it _ES2017_? I've never understood. It seems like setting itself up to fail; it's 2017 now and we still can't use _ES2015/16_ in production client code without a transpiler because of legacy browsers, mobile browsers, safari, etc

Comment: So if my browser supports es2017 I can use it in node? Or node.js must be compatible with it too?

Comment: @PaulS. It's because ever since ES2015 (or ES6) ECMA has decided to release a spec every year with all the proposal that are ready in the spec. It's not really a factor that modern browsers and implementations have not caught up. The year means the spec release year, not that all features will be implemented and usable in that year

Comment: @PaulS. https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm - the standard is called ECMA-262 ES2017 8th edition. I find ES2017 less ambiguous than ES8 simply because the standard name is ES2017 or ES2017 8th edition, not ES8.

Comment: V8 is an engine — it's software that executes your Javascript code. It's not an implementation of ES8.

Comment: @MichaelR it as a standard compliant runtime surely implements the standard.

Comment: @zerkms Granted, you're right... but V8 is mostly written in C++ and doesn't implement the standard in the same sense that JavaScript or ActionScript do. I just thought referring to it as an implementation of ES8 is a little confusing.